# Why do I keep getting this title match error with my Python program?

Tags: python

When I run the following code, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\j-a-c-o-b\newlc.py", line 94, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\j-a-c-o-b\newlc.py", line 71, in main
    for final_url in pool.imap(handle_listing, listings):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg\eventlet\greenpool.py", line 232, in next
    val = self.waiters.get().wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg\eventlet\greenthread.py", line 166, in wait
    return self._exit_event.wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg\eventlet\event.py", line 120, in wait
    current.throw(*self._exc)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\eventlet-0.9.16-py2.7.egg\eventlet\greenthread.py", line 192, in main
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Robert\Documents\j-a-c-o-b\newlc.py", line 35, in handle_listing
    title, = TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

What is wrong?

It has something to do with the Title match but I don't know how to fix it!

If you could help me I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

```
from gzip import GzipFile
from cStringIO import StringIO
import re
import webbrowser
import time
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import os
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import eventlet
from eventlet.green import urllib2
import urllib2
import urllib

def download(url):
    print "Downloading:", url
    s = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    if s[:2] == '\x1f\x8b':
        ifh = GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=StringIO(s))
        s = ifh.read()
    print "Downloaded: ", url
    return s

def replace_chars(text, replacements):
    return ''.join(replacements.get(x,x) for x in text)

def handle_listing(listing_url):
    listing_document = BeautifulSoup(download(listing_url))

    # ignore pages that link to yellowpages
    if not listing_document.find("a", href=re.compile(re.escape("http://www.yellowpages.com/") + ".*")):
        listing_title = listing_document.title.text
        reps = {' ':'-', ',':'', '\'':'', '[':'', ']':''}
        title, = TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()
        address, = ADDRESS_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()

        yellow_page_url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/%s/%s?order=distance" % (
            replace_chars(address, reps),
            replace_chars(title, reps),
        )

        yellow_page = BeautifulSoup(download(yellow_page_url))

        page_url = yellow_page.find("h3", {"class" : "business-name fn org"})
        if page_url:
            page_url = page_url.a["href"]

            business_name = title[:title.index(",")]

            page = BeautifulSoup(download(page_url))
            yellow_page_address =  page.find("span", {"class" : "street-address"})
            if yellow_page_address:

                if SequenceMatcher(None, address, yellow_page_address.text).ratio() >= 0.5:
                    pid, = re.search(r'p(\d{5,20})\.jsp', listing_url).groups(0)
                    page_escaped = replace_chars(page_url, {':':'%3A', '/':'%2F', '?':'%3F', '=':'%3D'})

                    final_url = "http://www.locationary.com/access/proxy.jsp?ACTION_TOKEN=proxy_jsp$JspView$SaveAction&inPlaceID=%s&xxx_c_1_f_987=%s" % (
                            pid, page_escaped)
                    return final_url


def main():

    pool = eventlet.GreenPool()
    listings_document = BeautifulSoup(download(START_URL))
    listings = listings_document.findAll("a", href = LOCATION_LISTING)
    listings = [listing['href'] for listing in listings]

    for final_url in pool.imap(handle_listing, listings):
        print final_url


        if str(final_url) is not None:

            url = str(final_url)

            req = urllib2.Request(url)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
            page = response.read()
            time.sleep(2)



for a in range(2,3):

    START_URL = 'http://www.locationary.com/place/en/US/New_Jersey/Randolph-page' + str(a) + '/?ACTION_TOKEN=NumericAction'
    TITLE_MATCH = re.compile(r'(.*) \(\d{1,10}.{1,100}\)$')
    ADDRESS_MATCH = re.compile(r'.{1,100}\((.*), .{4,14}, United States\)$')
    LOCATION_LISTING = re.compile(r'http://www\.locationary\.com/place/en/US/.{1,50}/.{1,50}/.{1,100}\.jsp')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from your error:

> title, = TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

`TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title)` returns `None`, so you can't call `.groups()`.

Comment: So would I put:   `if TITLE_MATCH is not None:`

Comment: No. You'll want to check the output of `match()`, not the actual regex itself.

Comment: `if TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title) not None:`       (just making it a little clearer

Answer (score 2):

When a `re` `.match` does not find anything to match, it returns `None`.  Since you cannot call `.groups()` on `None`, you have to check for a match first.  To do that:

Change this:

```
title, = TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()
address, = ADDRESS_MATCH.match(listing_title).groups()
```

To this:

```
titleMatch = TITLE_MATCH.match(listing_title)
if titleMatch:
    title, = titleMatch.groups()
else:
    # handle it

addressMatch = ADDRESS_MATCH.match(listing_title)
if addressMatch:
    address, = addressMatch.groups()
else:
    # handle it
```